# Crear una nueva columna en un dataframe en base a los valores de otra columna si cumplen una de tres condiciones

Tags: r, dataframe

Estoy trabajando con un dataframe que contiene la columna review_scores_rating cada campo de esta columna contiene valores entre el 1 y el 100. Necesito crear una nueva columna en función de que, si el valor del campo de la columna review_scores_rating es de 0 a 49, sea “NO ACONSEJABLE”; de 50 a 75 sea “ESTÁNDAR”; y de 76 a 100 sea “TOP”.

He intentado:

```
df_nuevo$CATEGORIA <- ifelse(df_nuevo$review_scores_rating <= 49, "NO ACONSEJABLE", "ESTÁNDAR")
df_nuevo$CATEGORIA <- ifelse(df_nuevo$review_scores_rating >= 76 & df_nuevo$CATEGORIA != "NO ACONSEJABLE" , "TOP", "ESTÁNDAR")
```

Haciendo esto la segunda sentencia me ´´pisa`` los valores <=49
También he probado con:

```
df_nuevo$CATEGORIA <- ifelse(df_nuevo$review_scores_rating <= 49, "NO ACONSEJABLE", "ESTÁNDAR")
filter(df_nuevo, review_scores_rating >= 76) %>% df_nuevo$CATEGORIA <- "TOP"
```

Lo siento si mi duda es muy básica pero llevo bastantes horas buscando y no doy con la solución, ¿habría alguna función equivalente a un switch para dataframes que me permita realizar esto?, o alguna otra manera de conseguirlo.
He probado multitud de cosas diferentes pero no quiero hacer la pregunta innecesariamente larga. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de resolverlo, algunas podrían ser estas:

#### `ifelse()` anidados

```
df_nuevo$CATEGORIA <- ifelse(df_nuevo$review_scores_rating <= 49, 
                             "NO ACONSEJABLE",
                             ifelse(df_nuevo$review_scores_rating <= 75,
                                    "ESTÁNDAR",
                                    "TOP"))
```

---

Es parecido a lo que has intentado, la diferencia es que anidamos condiciones para cubrir las tres categorías

#### `cut()` para recortar rangos

Esta solución puede parecer algo rara, pero es muy óptima, `cut()` transforma una variable continua en una discreta en función a un rango predefinido, con esto logramos los índices que haremos coincidir con los nombres de la categorias

```
df_nuevo$CATEGORIA <- c("NO ACONSEJABLE", "ESTÁNDAR", "TOP")[cut(df_nuevo$review_scores_rating, c(-Inf, 49, 75, Inf))]
```

---

#### `case_when()` de `dplyr`

Es básicamente una sintaxis parecida a un `CASE WHEN` de `SQL`

```
df_nuevo %>% 
  mutate(CATEGORIA = case_when(
    review_scores_rating <= 49 ~ "NO ACONSEJABLE",
    review_scores_rating <= 75 ~ "ESTÁNDAR",
    TRUE ~ "TOP"
  ))
```